# Selenium RC: How to verfiy the format/Datatype of a table columns

Tags: selenium-rc

There are three columns in a table: 'ID', 'Name', 'DoB' with datatype as number, string and date resp. 
now i need to verify that data displayed in each column matches its datatype.
How can i do this in Selenium RC?

Answer (score 0):

Extract everything as string and then apply regular expressions.

Comment: there is no command available like Assertformat() or something, where i can just give the xpath of the column as target and the format like string as value...?

Comment: Neither selenium nor junit provide any facility like that.Anyways it looks very non-generic requirement.You can simply type cast your variables in your desired format and while typecasting if you get exception then the value will not be in desired format.That's where the case ends.